# Disabling registration cache in MPICH3.2

Tags: mpi, mpich, mvapich2

When using MVAPICH2 I export this variable:

> MV2_USE_LAZY_MEM_UNREGISTER=0

In the [user guide](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/linux_clusters/mvapich_user_guide_2.1-5.pdf) this variable is defined as:

*"Setting this parameter enables mvapich2 to use memory registration cache."*

If I needed to use this feature in MPICH, which could be its equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no registration cache in MPICH, this is a feature which is specific to MVAPICH